# Sort array of Trello cards by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime, trello

I'm getting cards assigned to the user using the [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/index.html). It's an array called `cards`. Each item in the array has another array nested inside it, with the properties of each card inside it.

So I have my `cards` array, and then each Object inside it has it's own array.

E.g:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
        due: 2013-11-29T12:00:00.000Z
    1: Object
        due: 2013-11-26T12:00:00.000Z
    2: Object
        due: 2013-12-28T12:00:00.000Z
```

I want to sort my `cards` by the `due` property of the `cards`.

I get this array like this:

```
    Trello.get("members/me/cards", function(cards) {
        console.log(cards);
    });
```

And I can get each `due` property with `console.log(dates[1].due)`

So my question is, how can I order these Objects by this datetime?

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759127/2247494)**

Answer (score 2):

All JS arrays have a built in sort function.
`cards.sort(function(a,b) {
      a1 = new Date(a.due);
      b1 = new Date(b.due);
      return a1<b1? -1: a1 > b ? 1 : 0);
}`

Comment: Yes.  Additionally, if the values are all at UTC (they all have a `Z` on them) you can omit creating a `Date` object and just sort them as strings, since they are then lexicographically sortable.

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759127/2247494)**